# Check the attribute of items in a directory in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have made this little code to check how many subdirectories are in a given directory. It checks only the first level, is there anyway I can make it simplier? I have added comments, maybe easier to understand my intention. Thank you!

> ```
>     #import < Foundation/Foundation.h >            
>             int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
> ```

```
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];



// insert code here...
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSMutableArray *listOfFiles;
NSDictionary *listOfFolders;
NSDictionary *controllDir;
int i, count;
NSString *myPath;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

myPath = @"/";

// list the files in the given directory (myPath)

listOfFiles = [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath: myPath];

// count the number of elements in the array
count = [listOfFiles count];

// check them one by one
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // I need the full path
   NSString *filePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", myPath, [listOfFiles objectAtIndex: i]];

    // add every item with its attributes
    listOfFolders = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];

    // to avoid typo get the attribute and create a string
    controllDir = [filemgr attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/" error:NULL];
    NSString *toCheck = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [controllDir objectForKey:NSFileType]];   

    // the folder elements one by one
    NSString *fileType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [listOfFolders objectForKey:NSFileType]];    


    if([toCheck isEqualToString:fileType])
        {
            NSLog(@"NAME: %@  TYPE: %@" ,[listOfFiles objectAtIndex:i],[listOfFolders objectForKey:NSFileType]);
        }                
}            

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url
                      includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array]
                      options:0
                      error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *dirs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSURL *url in items) {
        if (CFURLHasDirectoryPath((CFURLRef)url)) {
            [dirs addObject:url];
        }
    }
}
```

You can get fancy with blocks this way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
        ^BOOL (id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){
            return CFURLHasDirectoryPath((CFURLRef)evaluatedObject); }];
NSArray *dirs = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Of note here is that it only hits the disk the one time, and it doesn't spend any time fetching unneeded attributes. Once you construct the `NSURL`, you can always tell if it's a directory because it ends in a / (this is specified behavior). That's all `CFURLHasDirectoryPath()` is doing. It doesn't actually hit the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Brief thoughts (posting from a cell phone):

- use an [`NSDirectoryEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath%3a).
- it has a method called [`fileAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDirectoryEnumerator/fileAttributes) that will return an `NSDictionary` with the item's attributes.
- `NSDictionary` has a `fileType` method that will return a constant to indicate the kind of the item.
- there's a nice constant called `NSFileTypeDirectory` you can use for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *subpaths = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:&error];
if (!subpaths) ...handle error.
NSMutableArray *subdirs = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *name in subpaths)
{
    NSString *subpath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    BOOL isDir;
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:subpath isDirectory:&isDir] &&
        isDir)
    {
        [subdirs addObject:subpath];
    }
}
```

Now the `subdirs` array contains all of the immediate subdirectories.

Comment: My only concern with this, that if I check the content of the array, gives me back only numbers and not the name of the folders. What did O do wrong?